# accesing a specific element in a 2D list by row and column

Tags: python-3.x

ok , so for one of my assignments I need to print out the  3rd element in the second row of the 2D List. Below is provided code

```
# Get our list from the command line arguments
import sys
list2d= sys.argv[1:]

# Convert the command line arguments into 2d list
for i in range(0,len(list2d)):  
  list2d[i]= list2d[i].split(',')

# Write your code below

r = 0  
c = 0

for row in list2d:  
  for element in row:  
    r = element[1];  
for col in list2d:  
  for element in column:  
    c = element[2];  

print(element[r, c])
```

Comment: You don't need any loops for this. Just `print(list2d[1][2])`

Comment: Thank you. That helped. I realize now I was overthinking it. Again thank you